# Add datas to my SQL using dynamic fields not working

Tags: jquery, mysql, dynamic, field

```
<?php
$qry=mysql_query("INSERT INTO ingredients(item,quantity,unm)VALUES('$items','$quantitys','$unm')", $con);//edited
?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){

    //variables
    var html = '<p/><div>item: <input type="text" name="item" id="childitem"/>quantity: <input type="text" name="quantity" id="childquantity"/><a href="#" id="remove"> X </a></div>';
    var maxrows = 25;
    var x = 1; 

    //add rows to the form
    $("#add").click(function(e){
        if(x <= maxrows){
        $("#container").append(html);
            x++;
        }
    });

    //remove rows 
    $("#container").on('click','#remove',function(e){
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Where do you set `$items`?

Comment: All your inputs have the same `name="item"`. When you submit the form, PHP will only see the last one. You should use an array-style `name="item[]"`, then `$_POST['item']` will be an array of all the inputs.

Comment: Also, IDs must be unique, you can't have `id="childitem"` on all of them. Use a class instead.

Comment: In your PHP, you should have a loop to process all the inputs.

Comment: could you please define loop

Comment: `foreach ($_POST['item'] as $item)`

Comment: What kind of programmer doesn't know what a loop is?

Comment: sorry, im new to prgramming.

Comment: @RiyAsMuhaMmed it must be week 1 of your course then if you don't know about looping. Lastly, your SQL is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. Get into good habits _now_ and learn to use parameterised queries. You can find a tutorial anywhere. Otherwise an attacker could find a way to delete all your data.

Comment: @Barmar could you please look in to this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42219786/form-didnt-working-with-mysql