# form didnt working with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms

> this is the html

```
<form action="addadd.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
    <p>
        First Name<br>
        <label for="firstname"></label>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" />
    </p>
    <p>
        Last Name<br>
        <label for="lastname"></label>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" />
    </p>
    <p>
        Mobile<br>
        <label for="mobile"></label>
        <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" />
    </p>
    <p>
        Email<br>
        <label for="email"></label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" /> 
        <input type="reset" name="button3" id="button3" value="Reset" />
    </p>
</form>
```

> This is the php
>
> database connection

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con)
{
die("connection to database failed".mysql_error());
}
$dataselect = mysql_select_db("qoot",$con);
if(!$dataselect)
{
die("Database namelist not selected".mysql_error());
}
?>


<?php 
    $unm = $_SESSION['name']; 
    $fname=$_POST['firstname']; 
    $lname=$_POST['lastname']; 
    $ema=$_POST['email'];
    $mob=$_POST['mobile'];
?>



<?php 
    $qry=mysql_query("INSERT INTO address( firstname, lastname, mobile, email)VALUES('$fname',$lname','$ema','$mob')", $con);
?>
```

Now the problem is that this is inserting nothing in to my database.
What else can i try in order to check where things go wrong?
updated database connection details

Comment: what do you mean with "not working"? Is there any error?

Comment: its not saving the data to mysql

Comment: first off: stop using the mysql api and use the mysqli (mysql improved) or PDO instead. Second: Never put unescaped user input (get, post etc) into a query like that, use prepared statements or escape the values! Third: Show errors or explain what is not working, also show the html code for the form.

Comment: Unescaped data into a query opens up for sql-injection attacks, which is a bad thing. the `mysql` api is deprecated and is not even present in newer versions of php.

Comment: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2 align="center">Add Products</h2>
<form action="addadd.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
<p>First Name<br>
<label for="firstname"></label>
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" />
</p>
<p>Last Name<br>

Comment: <label for="lastname"></label>
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" />
</p>
<p>Mobile<br>
<label for="mobile"></label>
<input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" />
</p>
<p>Email<br>
<label for="email"></label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" /> 
<input type="reset" name="button3" id="button3" value="Reset" />
</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @RiyAsMuhaMmed Did you include your db connection file?

Comment: <?php


$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con)
{
die("connection to database failed".mysql_error());
}

/* selecting the database "cms" */
$dataselect = mysql_select_db("qoot",$con);
if(!$dataselect)
{
die("Database namelist not selected".mysql_error());
}
?>

Comment: Please edit question and add code there rather than new comments.

Comment: @RiyAsMuhaMmed is the db connection code above in a different page?

Comment: no.in same page

Comment: @RiyAsMuhaMmed pls post your entire code

Comment: @RiyAsMuhaMmed your php code doesnt show the connection code..pls update that too

Comment: Add error checking to the end of the `mysql_query()` line: `$qry = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your tablename `address` in backticks

Using `mysqli_`

```
  <?php
/start session
session_start();
//establish connection
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","qoot");
if(!$con)
{
die("connection to database failed".mysqli_error($con));
}
     //read the values from form
    $unm = $_SESSION['name']; 
    $fname=$_POST['firstname']; 
    $lname=$_POST['lastname']; 
    $ema=$_POST['email'];
    $mob=$_POST['mobile'];
?>



<?php 
   //insert to database
    $qry=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `address` ( firstname, lastname, mobile, email)VALUES('$fname',$lname','$ema','$mob')") or die(mysqli_error($con));
?>
```

P.S I'd say you are at risk of `mysql injection`, check here [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). You should really use prepared statements to avoid any risk.

Comment: there is no errors, but nothing is updated in database.

Comment: echo the values of firstname,lastname,email and mobile before insert query

Comment: now iam using my sqli, but now warning mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\qoot\addadd.php on line 64

Comment: it needs a database connection string and your query. e.g mysqli_query ($db_connect, $sql);

Comment: sorry, its not working. i think there is problem with inserting data

Comment: If you're going to show how to switch to mysqli, you should also show how to write it using a prepared statement to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: The first line of the answer says to put the table name in backticks. Where are the backticks? But `address` isn't a reserved word, so it doesn't need to be escaped like that.

Comment: @Barmar Oh..i forgot to correct it in the answer..I know its not a reserved word but the error is probably in the query..so just mentioned to clear it out.

Comment: @Barmar I converted OP's current code to mysqli_ so it would be easy for him to understand at the beginning. You are right..Il edit it that way too

Comment: @Barmar Thanks :)

Comment: @RiyAsMuhaMmed  Didnt it show any error in the query after adding mysqli_error after insert query

Comment: @RiyAsMuhaMmed Update your post with the latest code

Comment: the code is working.thanks every one. but when i put the table name as address it didnt works,so i changed the table name.now its working fine. thanks all.thank you barmar , affaz.

Comment: @RiyAsMuhaMmed Yes..it wouldnt be a problem if you put backticks in your query for `address`

Comment: @RiyAsMuhaMmed Not sure why you got an error from using `address` as the table name. It doesn't have any special meaning. What was the error message?

Comment: @Barmar there is no error message, the values are passing to tables, but it didnt showing in db.

Comment: @Barmar please look this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42888702/variables-passing-nothing-shows-undefined-variable-error-so-want-to-put-default