# variables passing nothing shows undefined variable error, so want to put default value for variable

Tags: php, mysql, variables

The problem is on the variable `$tot`, `$tot` add and give value for three other variables, i.e. `$seone`, `$setwo`, `$sethree`.
but in some case either one of the variable didn't have value passing in it, so that put undefinded variable error in pages. I need to put default value zero if there is no value passing in these variables, I tried a lot, didn't fixed.

```
<BR>
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(id) AS total FROM recevd where packages = '110 PER PERSON'");
$values=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$num_two=$values['total'];
echo $num_two.'&nbsp;CUSTOMERS FOR PACKAGE 110 PER PERSON';
?>

<BR>
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(id) AS total FROM recevd where packages = '120 PER PERSON'");
$values=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$num_three=$values['total'];
echo $num_three.'&nbsp;CUSTOMERS FOR PACKAGE 120 PER PERSON';
?>

<br>
<br>




DAILY NEEDED QUANTITY FOR
<?php
/*
isset() is used to check wheather arctile id is received through url from "index.php" file and if it is set corresponding arctile is displayted using SELECT statement.
*/

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
$id=$_GET['id'];
$qry=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM addingre WHERE id=$id", $con);
if(!$qry)
{
die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
}

                /* Fetching data from the field "title" */
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{
$ttt= $row['ingredients'];
}
}
?>
<?php
echo '<h2>'."$ttt".'</h2>';
$hh = '7';
?>




<br>
100 Per Person<br>
<?php
$query_check_credentials = "SELECT product, SUM(quantity) AS total_amount FROM ingredients WHERE item = '$ttt' AND package = '100 PER PERSON' GROUP BY product";
$res = mysql_query($query_check_credentials);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                echo $row['total_amount']*$num_one /'1000'.'(KG/LI)';
                $seone = $row['total_amount']*$num_one.'(KG/LI)';


}
?>
<br>
110 Per Person<br>
<?php
$query_check_credentials = "SELECT product, SUM(quantity) AS total_amount FROM ingredients WHERE item = '$ttt' AND package = '110 PER PERSON' GROUP BY product";

$res = mysql_query($query_check_credentials);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                echo $row['total_amount']*$num_two/'1000'.'(KG/LI)';
                $setwo = $row['total_amount']*$num_two.'(KG/LI)';
}
?>

<br>
120 Per Person<br>
<?php
$query_check_credentials = "SELECT product, SUM(quantity) AS total_amount FROM ingredients WHERE item = '$ttt' AND package = '120 PER PERSON' GROUP BY product";

$res = mysql_query($query_check_credentials);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                echo $row['total_amount']*$num_three/'1000'.'(KG/LI)';
                $sethree = $row['total_amount']*$num_three.'(KG/LI)';
}
?>
<br>
<h3>TOTAL QUANTITY NEEDED FOR THE DAY <?php
echo $time_now;
 ?> = 
<?php
$query_check_credentials = "SELECT product, SUM(quantity) AS total_amount FROM ingredients WHERE item = '$ttt' GROUP BY product";
$res = mysql_query($query_check_credentials);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                $tot = $seone+$setwo+$sethree;
                echo $tot/1000 .'(KG/LI)';


}
?>
</h3>


<br>

Weekly Needed Quanity
<br><br>


100 Per Person<br>
<?php
$query_check_credentials = "SELECT product, SUM(quantity) AS total_amount FROM ingredients WHERE item = '$ttt' AND package = '100 PER PERSON' GROUP BY product";
$res = mysql_query($query_check_credentials);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                echo $row['total_amount']*$num_one*$hh/'1000'.'(KG/LI)';



}
?>
<br>
110 Per Person<br>
<?php
$query_check_credentials = "SELECT product, SUM(quantity) AS total_amount FROM ingredients WHERE item = '$ttt' AND package = '110 PER PERSON' GROUP BY product";

$res = mysql_query($query_check_credentials);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                echo $row['total_amount']*$num_two*$hh/'1000'.'(KG/LI)';

}
?>

<br>
120 Per Person<br>
<?php
$query_check_credentials = "SELECT product, SUM(quantity) AS total_amount FROM ingredients WHERE item = '$ttt' AND package = '120 PER PERSON' GROUP BY product";

$res = mysql_query($query_check_credentials);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                echo $row['total_amount']*$num_three*$hh/'1000'.'(KG/LI)';

}
?>




<h3><h3>TOTAL QUANTITY NEEDED FOR THE NEXT 7 days <?php
echo $time_now;
 ?> -to- <?php echo $time_end ?> = 

<?php
$query_check_credentials = "SELECT product, SUM(quantity) AS total_amount FROM ingredients WHERE item = '$ttt' GROUP BY product";
$res = mysql_query($query_check_credentials);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
               $tot = $seone*$hh+$setwo*$hh+$sethree*$hh;
                echo $tot/1000 .'(KG/LI)';



}
?>
```

Comment: @barmar please look in to this script

Comment: You're overwriting `$seone`, `$setwo`, and `$sethree` each time through the loops, so it will just contain the quantity from the last product returned by each query. And why are you putting `(KG/LI)` at the end of these variables if you're planning on adding them as numbers?

Comment: If you want them to have the value 0 if the queries don't return any rows, assign `0` to them before the `while` loops.

Comment: Why are you assigning to `$tot` in a loop? That loop doesn't use anything from the query.

Comment: You can combine all those queries into a single query: `SELECT product, package, SUM(quantity) AS total_amount FROM ingredients WHERE item = '$ttt' GROUP BY product, package`.

Comment: thanks @barmar , its worked, you are the man..